# Apache Spark MLlib Model File Format

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Apache Spark MLlib algorithms (e.g., Decision Trees) save the model in a location (e.g., `myModelPath`) where it creates two directories, viz. `myModelPath/data` and `myModelPath/metadata`. There are multiple files in these paths and those are not text files. There are some files of format `*.parquet`.

I have couple of questions:

- What are the format of these files?
- Which file/files contain actual model?
- Can I save the model to somewhere else, for example in a DB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Spark >= 2.4**

Since Spark 2.4 provides format agnostic writer interfaces and selected models already implement these. For example `LinearRegressionModel`:

```scala
val lrm: org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegressionModel = ???
val path: String = ???

lrm.write.format("pmml").save(path)
```

will create a directory with a single file containing [PMML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictive_Model_Markup_Language) representation.

**Spark < 2.4**

> What are the format of these files?

- `data/*.parquet` files are in [Apache Parquet](https://parquet.apache.org/) columnar storage format
- `metadata/part-*` looks like JSON

> Which file/files contain actual model?

- `model/*.parquet`

> Can I save the model to somewhere else, for example in a DB?

I am not aware of any direct method but you can load model as a data frame and store it in a database afterwards:

```scala
val modelDf = spark.read.parquet("/path/to/data/")
modelDf.write.jdbc(...)
```