# How is it possible to run a spark mlib decision tree model in pure python?

Tags: python, apache-spark, decision-tree, pmml

I want to build models (specifically - decision trees) using spark, and later apply them using a pure python (not pyspark) application

It appears that PMML export is the intended method, but it's not yet supported for tree models, and I didn't find a PMML library for python that appears to be in active development

Answer (score 2):

No longer under development is  Augustus, at https://code.google.com/p/augustus/ . More recently there has been work to support scikitlearn pmml import/export at https://github.com/alex-pirozhenko/sklearn-pmml which could be an option.

As noted by @zero323 PMML export is only available for certain models. For other models, if you are targeting a specific serving platform you can write your own custom export code or write your own parsing code (for Decission Tree's is written out in a custom parquet format which).

Comment: There is no PMML writer for DecisionTreeModel so it won't work here.

Comment: Ah yes, thats a good point (this just answered the part of the question about where to get PMML support in Python).

Comment: Yep, since decision trees are relatively simple something like this should be sufficient: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31975050/1560062

Comment: Currently, alex-pirozhenko/sklearn-pmml only does the export of Python models to PMML (and not vice versa). So, it's probably not very helpful if you're still missing a PMML consumer for Python.

Comment: Ah good catch, so that really only leave Augustus which is not really all that active as far as development goes.