# Controlling number of files when saving MLlib model

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

When using model.save() to save an MLlib model to S3, is there a way to control the number of parquet files created?  I know that if I were saving an RDD or data frame, I can control this by repartitioning the data, but cannot find any reference on saving a model.

Comment: In spark 2.4+ you can save the model as a single pmml file, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31973116/apache-spark-mllib-model-file-format

Comment: Thank you.  Is it possible to save the model in multiple files, just with me being able to control that number?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible or not, sorry. Just out of curiosity, why so you want a specific number of files when saving the model?

Comment: To speed up saving very large models.